# Setting up an NTP server for my LAN

Tags: linux, ntpd

I am trying to setup my Debian 6 (Squeeze) VM to act as a local time server for my network. I have it set to sync with `tock.usno.navy.mil` which is a stratum 1 server.

I am having some problems finding any information on how to setup the ntp daemon to serve the time to clients requesting the time. I have looked through the ntpd man page and that was probably the best doc I found. [support.ntp.org](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Main/WebHome) was pretty much useless to me, the documentation I found was talking more about how NTP works not how to configure a server.

I also noticed I am not getting anything in my logs about being synced with the server that I am listed.

Any help anyone can offer would be great, I am not sure what is wrong. I am sure it is something I am doing. I had a previous time server running but my SAN blew up and I was not making backups since it was for testing. So I have no old config to look at.

Here is a copy of `ntp.conf` since there is nothing in here that has a any personal information I thought posting might help.

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift


# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable


# You do need to talk to an NTP server or two (or three).
#server ntp.your-provider.example

# pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will
# pick a different set every time it starts up.  Please consider joining the
# pool: <http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html>
server tock.usno.navy.mil iburst


# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for
# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>
# might also be helpful.
#
# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration
# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end
# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.

# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict 10.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrap nomodify

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if
# cryptographically authenticated.
#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust


# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.
# (Again, the address is an example only.)
#broadcast 192.168.123.255

# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the
# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network!
#disable auth
#broadcastclient
```

Here the output from `ntpq -p`

```
root@ns01:/home/ns01# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 ntp1.usno.navy. .USNO.           1 u   43   64    1   34.747  -2891.0 1669.51
```

Output from iptables

```
Output from `iptables -L -n -v`

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**Update**

When I remove the line `restrict 10.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrap nomodify` from my config ntp seems to spring to life. This is what I see now when I look at `ntpq -p`

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
-barricade.rack9 209.51.161.238   2 u   39   64  377   37.887  -2977.7   3.180
*gallifrey.chpc. 92.113.67.127    2 u   26   64  377   68.155  -2969.0   3.024
+clock.trit.net  204.34.198.41    2 u    2   64  377   83.146  -2972.0   3.756
+ntp1.Housing.Be 169.229.128.214  3 u   63   64  377  105.803  -2972.6   2.698
```

Test Desktop ifconfig output (requested by MadHatter)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:59:2d:3a  
          inet addr:10.0.0.21  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe59:2d3a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:62103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:51822 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10339609 (9.8 MiB)  TX bytes:7249927 (6.9 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5066 (4.9 KiB)  TX bytes:5066 (4.9 KiB)
```

Comment: As it does to some other posters, your NTP config seems fine to me, so I suspect firewalling.  Could we get the output of `iptables -L -n -v` on the server and on the client that can't do an ntpdate?  `ifconfig -a` from the client that can't ntpdate would also be helpful, just for completeness' sake.

Comment: added the iptables output

Comment: I use a pfsense box to keep things out of my LAN. Even with my windows boxes I only run a LAN firewall if I see a reason. For Linux I keep it default. Mainly because I am still figuring things out.

Comment: Linux default can be fairly tightly tied-down, depending on the distro.  I presume the above iptables is from the server, could we get it from the debian desktop that failed to do "ntpdate"?  Also, the ifconfig output from the desktop, as requested.

Comment: Well thats the thing the ntpdate on the desktop works fine as long I don't try to sync to my LAN server (The one that is not working). If I sync to `time-a.nist.gov` it works fine. If you still think a ifconfig output would help I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insure that udp port 123 is open inbound to your server from your LAN and back out to your LAN from your server.

Also, you can check the status of your server's sync by running

"ntpq -p"

I'd recommend adding at least three upstream servers to your config.

Try pointing one of your clients to your server via "ntpdate servername" and see what happens.

Comment: When I run ntpdate on my Debian 6 Desktop I get "14 Apr 02:22:51 ntpdate[6601]: no server suitable for synchronization found"

Comment: I added the output from ntpq -p to my question

Comment: firewall config on the server?

Comment: I added the firewall output, there are no rules in it. Unless they are hidden or something.

Comment: Stop ntpd, run ntpdate time.nist.gov.  Your sync is off.  You may need to run ntpdate twice.

Add more ntp servers to your server then restart ntpd.  Keep running ntpq -p until you see signs your server has optained a proper sync.  See: man ntpq section on peers.  Once you get that, try ntpdate from your client again.

Comment: I went back to the default config just to see if it was the server I was using. The default points to 4 pool.ntp.org servers. Still not working

Comment: I will try to sync thing you mentioned

Comment: The sync thing made no difference, oddly enough though. When I remove the like `restrict 10.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrap nomodify` from my config it seems to come to life when I look @ `ntpq -p` I will add a new output of what I am seeing now.

Comment: much better looking

Comment: So now I am having trouble understanding why my config line is wrong, or is it ok?

Comment: Your server is working.  The * and # symbols next to your peers let you know you are sync'd up.  I'm still trying to figure out why you have such a huge offset.  As far as why your client can't connect, I suspeect you need some kind of ACL or restrict line.  I'm not running any ntp servers at the moment so I can't check on a working config.  Does ntpdate yourserver work from your client?

Comment: try removing all the restrict lines

Comment: Ok I removed the restrict lines and added the one you listed, I had to keep `restrict 127.0.0.1` because `ntpq` could not connect to ntpd because it was denied `query` ability.

Comment: just remove all

Comment: it does not work if I do

Comment: The server has been up for a minute or two now, and unlike my output I posted form `ntpq -p` this output is missing the symbols that tells me what server ntp is peered with and such.

Comment: wait for those symbols, you can run "watch ntpq -pn".  Once you get a sync, on your client try ntpdate yourserver

Comment: No dice, the server still will not do anything. I am thinking removing the two lines for defaults may have angered ntpd

Comment: Ok ok stop the presses this is too weird! I started to think maybe it was a bug in the NTP package (I am grasping a staws here). So I load up a "well used" ubuntu 10.10 server on my ESXi box, same one running the server this question is about. All I had to do to make it work was `apt-get install ntp` I did not have to touch the config AT ALL. I repeat no config needed!. What the heck is going on? I think I might go back to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with dmourati's answer. Your configuration seems correct. The only additional thing I'd recommend checking is whether your ntpd process is running at all.

With regard to documentation: I have recently set up a Meinberg GPS time card, and found their [documentation](http://www.meinberg.de/english/info/ntp.htm#cfg_server_unix) quite helpful. For your use case, you'd just have to ignore all references to dedicated PCI cards and use a proper server name instead of the pseudo IP address that's used to refer to the PCI card.

However, I think you may be losing quite some precision by putting your local time server on a virtual machine. If you need sub-second precision on your network, be sure to measure the precision of your local server. The [Time Nuts](http://www.leapsecond.com/time-nuts.htm) page may be a good starting point to look for approaches to this.

Comment: I don't need crazy actuate time, I am just using a time server to keep my entire network in sync with one clock. I could just sync to a server on the outside but this way I reduce the amount of traffic I am sending out.